# Tensorflow - predicting sequences: what is X and Y?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have a tensor that needs to predict the next element in a sequence with a tensorflow LSTM/RNN, while taking into account the previous 5 elements. What should I feed into X and Y?

From 1 2 3 4 5, I want to predict 6

Suppose my input sequence X is:

```
X = 1 2 3 4 5 
    6 7 8 9 10 
    11 12 13 14 15
    ...
```

Would my Y be:

```
Y = 2 3 4 5 6 
    7 8 9 10 11 
    12 13 14 15 16
    ... ?
```

Or should I feed it:

```
X = 1 2 3 4 5 
    2 3 4 5 6
    3 4 5 6 7 
    ....
```

Would my Y be:

```
Y = 6
    7 
    8 
    ... ?
```

Or does TensorFlow do this automatically?

I am using the first approach now, inspired by a tutorial, with:

```
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, num_steps], name='input_placeholder')
    y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, num_steps], name='labels_placeholder')

    rnn_outputs = tf.reshape(rnn_outputs, [-1, state_size])
    y_reshaped = tf.reshape(y, [-1])
    logits = tf.matmul(rnn_outputs, W) + b
    predictions = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
    total_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels=y_reshaped))
```

If I ask for a prediction (in the actual code the time steps is 16 and number of classes is 14313, sorry for that):

```
        prevSlice = np.array([[1, 2 , 3 , 4, 5, 6 ,7, 8, 9 ,10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]], dtype=np.string_)
        feed_dict={g['x']: prevSlice}
        preds, state = sess.run([g['preds'],g['final_state']], feed_dict)
```

I get 15 predictions too many. Or how should I interpret these? I don't need predictions for the next 16 slices, just for the 1 next.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since an `LSTM` performs a `sequence to sequence` prediction, would this not mean that you're being given a sequence of `batch_size` length as the output of your predictor instead of a single timestep.

So in short you would be getting a sequence of the same size as a prediction.

Edit:

```
def predict_point_by_point(model, data):
    #Predict each timestep given the last sequence of true data, in effect only predicting 1 step ahead each time
    predicted = model.predict(data)
    predicted = np.reshape(predicted, (predicted.size,))
    return predicted
```

you could do something along those lines, and add a moving window for each `len(timestep)`
                                           that you feed onto your model accounting for that one timestep added so you output one at a time aswell.

Comment: Thanks! It seems like that is what happening. I'm just wondering if it's more efficient to do it one step at a time. Also, suppose I want to pick the most probably sequence of 16. Do I just pick the most likely from each of the 16 vectors (meaning: they take into account that if I pick the most likely 1st that the most likely 2nd will match that 1st)?

Comment: I think the most sensible thing would be pick the first in the prediction, and further predict by feeding a moving window onto the LSTM. cause the sequence would only give you one as the first element of the new sequence and their probabilities although different would refer to different timesteps.

Comment: I agree, that seems to make most sense. Thanks a lot for your help!