# How to interpret predictions in TensorFlow, they seem to have the wrong shape

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have a TensorFlow model with some of these characteristics:

```
    state_size = 800,
    num_classes = 14313,
    batch_size = 10,
    num_steps = 16, # width of the tensor
    num_layers = 3

   x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [batch_size, num_steps], name='input_placeholder')
   y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [batch_size, num_steps], name='labels_placeholder')
   rnn_inputs = [tf.squeeze(i, squeeze_dims=[1]) for i in
                  tf.split(x_one_hot, num_steps, 1)]  # still a list of tensors (batch_size, num_classes)
   ...
   logits = tf.matmul(rnn_outputs, W) + b

   predictions = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
```

Now I want to feed it a np.array (shape = batch_size x num_steps, so 10 x 16) and I get a predictions tensor back.

Weirdly, its shape is 160 x 14313. The latter is the number of classes. But where does 160 come from? I don't understand that. I would like to have a probability for each of my classes, for each of the elements of the batch (which is 10). How did the num_steps become involved, how to I read from this pred. tensor which is the expected element after those 16 numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case the 160 comes from the shape as you suspected.
which means that for each batch of 10, has 16 timesteps, this is technically flattened when you do your shape variable.
At this point you have logits of shape 160 * classes. so you can do `predictions[i]` for each batch which then will have the probability of each class being the desired class.
                                           which is why to get the chosen class you would do something like `tf.argmax(predictions, 1)` to get a tensor with the classification
this will have a shape of 160 in your case, so it will be the predicted
                                           class for each one of the batches.

In order to get the probabilities, you could use the [logits](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/52825/what-does-the-logit-value-actually-mean):

```
def prob(logit):
    return 1/(1 + np.exp(-logit)
```

Comment: I see, thank you.  Does softmax not give me the correct probabilities? I should use the exp function? So I think in my case I should actually be predicting only one value instead of 16. I have posted this in another question to avoid confusion. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42766458/tensorflow-predicting-sequences-what-is-x-and-y

Comment: tf.nn.softmax computes the forward propagation through a softmax layer. You use it during evaluation of the model when you compute the probabilities that the model outputs. so yes it would give you the correct probabilities, I wanted to provide another way just with the logits.

Comment: Related to this. I don't seem to know which label is related to which prediction value. This should be easy to get right? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43039055/how-to-get-class-labels-from-tensorflow-prediction